# validationKey on load balanced enviornments

Tags: config, load-balancer

In the Craft docs for [validationKey config settings](https://craftcms.com/docs/config-settings#validationKey), it states that `validationKey` should be used in load-balanced environments.

I'm curious on how to set this up for a load-balanced site. Does each  server need a different key, or should they all share the same setting in the config?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It should be the same for every server in the load balanced environment.

You should also set the [appId](https://craftcms.com/docs/config-settings#appId) config setting to a consistent value for every server in the cluster as well.

I've updated the documentation for those config settings to clarify.